# Jean Valjean and Halacha

Tags: halacha, literature

Note: This question is assuming that the character in question were Jewish, rather than Catholic. It is merely using the situations as examples.

In the musical adaptation of the Victor Hugo [classic](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Les%20Mis%C3%A9rables), [*Les Miserables*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Mis%C3%A9rables), the main character is mired in multiple situations which result in causing him much anguish. For example (spoilers):

> - When he hears that a man matching his description has been apprehended for his crimes, he agonises over whether to turn himself in (to not let an innocent man be convicted) or to maintain his cover (so as to aid the workers of his factory, who would lose their jobs were he arrested) (see "Who Am I")
> - He later evades arrest (at multiple times) to aid others

What would the halacha be in such situations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20163/discussion-between-noach-mi-frankfurt-and-shokhet).

Comment: What would the halacha for who be? What are the halachic questions at issue? BTW, congratulations on [being the first](http://data.stackexchange.com/judaism/query/290093/cases-of-use-of-spolier-formatting) on Mi Yodeya to use spolier formatting for its original intention.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, that's so cool! Also, um, think we ought to despoilerificate those other posts?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, that's actually DoubleAA's handiwork. I'd seen it on other boards, but I had no clue on either how to use it or whether it was appropriate for MY. I guess it is.